# What are the xp gains from the crackerjack merit awards

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

Two merit awards, crackerjack and crackerjack ii increase experience gained in battle. What is the increase exactly? Some kind of percentage? 5%, 10%?

Comment: Should be easy to calculate considering the exp values of monsters are listed in the compendium. All you have to do is subtract the difference from a battle and see for yourself. I would tell you but I havent yet got the above merit awards :( . Getting there ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The percentage increase from Crackerjack is 10% and Crackerjack II is 20%

Here is what I have observed. A Normal pack in the Winter Isles -

> - JabberGuppy
> - Lotus Bubbud
> - Sasquash

gives **243xp** without any bonuses.

With ***Crackerjack*** we get **266xp**.
With ***Crackerjack II*** we get **291xp**.

So lets compare with creature compendium -

> - JabberGuppy - **75xp**
> - Lotus Bubbud - **81xp**
> - Sasquash - **87xp**
>
> Total XP = 75 + 81 +87 = **243xp**.

Now with Crackerjack it should be
**243 + 10% = 243 + 24.3 = 267.3** which should be **267**.
But it is not because the bonus is calculated per creature!

so it would be -

> - JabberGuppy - **75xp** + 10% = 75+7.5 = 82.5 = **82xp**
> - Lotus Bubbud - **81xp** + 10% = 81+8.1 = 89.1 = **89xp**
> - Sasquash - **87xp** + 10% = 87+8.7 = 95.7 = **95xp**
>
> All fractions are rounded down.So now we get total to be
>
> Total XP = 82 + 89 + 95 = **266xp**!! (Which is what the game gives us)

Similarly with Crackerjack II -

> - JabberGuppy - **75xp** + 20% = 75+15 = **90xp**
> - Lotus Bubbud - **81xp** + 20% = 81+16.2 = 97.2 = **97xp**
> - Sasquash - **87xp** + 20% = 87+17.4 = 104.4 = **104xp**
>
> Total XP = 90 + 97 + 104 = **291xp**

In summary -

```
Crackerjack - 10% xp bonus monster xp
Crackerjack II - 20% xp bonus monster xp
```